# Race condition in Twilio API simul Rings

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am developing an application for handling calls. The architecture is simple. It rings 10 phones at the same time and when someone picks it, ring stops. But the issue I am facing is the race condition. if two reps picks the call I don't know how to instantly differentiate between who won the race and who didn't. It takes 5 seconds for twilio to send back a response

Is there anyone else faced the same issue before and found a solution, please share

Thanks

Comment: Are you using answering machine detection with these calls?

Comment: Nope. I am not using machine detection with these calls.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How have you implemented this so far then? Is then when you receive an incoming call?

Comment: Yes, if two people answer the call at a time, then I need to know instantly who answered it. Right now it takes 5 seconds to know who answered the call. Twilio I think doesn't provide this information.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can actually achieve a simulring using TwiML without having to handle which agent answers the phone yourself.

If you get an incoming call and you want to forward it to the first agent who answers, you can use [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) with up to 10 [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number)s. [Twilio will then ring all the numbers until one answers and will cancel the remaining calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#examples-2). Then there's no race condition for you to handle.

Let me know if that helps.